# Is the Sass linting rule for enforcing a space between the prop and value working incorrectly with VS Code?

Tags: sass, visual-studio-code, scss-lint

I have the latest version of Visual Studio Code (1.44.0) and the Sass extension (1.8.2), and am having an issue with a warning for: `Property should have one space Between the prop and value Sass(Property: 1)`, despite it being formatted properly. it appears it should be tied to the `"sass.format.setPropertySpace": false,` property

I have tried setting all the possible Sass linting options to ignore, but the warning persists.

[image: sass linting error]

Setting `"sass.lint.enable": false` doesn't prevent it, and the only way i can seem to prevent it, is to disable the Sass extension entirely.

Is there a settings property i am missing, or some other way to disable this? or is it a bug?

## UPDATE

i filed a ticket with the sass formatter, which can be found here https://github.com/TheRealSyler/sass-formatter/issues/23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it help!

image support!

go to setting and disable sass lint

Sass>Lint:Enable (unchecked )

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEfuL.png)

Comment: this is the correct answer, the reason why the message shows up is because i added a linter, but the linter project is halted it doesn't work correctly but its still there, disabling the linter is the way to go until i remove or improve the linter.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but I simply uninstalled the Sass extension from Syler and re-installed it, and boomm, it stopped showing the "property should have one space between the prop and value" issue.

I hope it helps!

Comment: so this does work... temporarily :) eventually it starts happening again, and i have to reinstall it again... but a temporary fix is better than nothing! i will post this bug to the sass extension github issues.. ty!